# Rabbi Zeira and Matthew 6, 1-4

Tags: talmud-gemara, christianity

I would like to know something about Rabbi Zeira (The short one with singed legs; Bava Metsia 85a). I read that a medieval polemicist (R. Shem Tov, XIV century) compares the saying of Jesus, contained in Matthew 6, 1-4, with what told or did Rabbi Zeira. I am unable to find the connection. The hebrew is: 
כל זה מדברי חז׳׳ל שכבר ידעת כמה הזהירו על זה ומעשה דקטינא חריך שקיה יוכיח

Can you kindly help me?

Thank you very much,

Miriam

Comment: I only know of a connection to Bava Batra 9b

Comment: It would help if you would tell us where your Hebrew quotation comes from. If you search it in Google, only this page comes up.

Comment: "I read that..." where did you read?

Comment: I have no idea what the alleged saying in the avodas zarah is about and cannot therefore compare it to anything.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you have provided no links to corroborate any quotes, I'll present this answer anyway.

The passages in Matthew discuss giving charity without anyone knowing. It is true that this is an idea found in the Talmud and later works. It is based on choosing death by fire rather than embarrassing someone. This is something we learn from Tamar in Genesis chapter 38. Bava Metzia 59a.

As far as mentioning Rabi Zeira, I think the author, if quoted correctly, has gotten confused.
There is a famous story in the Talmud in Kesuvos 67b where Mar Ukva and his wife chose to jump into a furnace rather than have the poor lady they were giving charity to find out who they were. I think that story got confused with the story of Rabi Zeira in Bava Metzia 85a who would enter a furnace once every thirty days to test his holiness to make sure the fires of hell would not affect him.

Comment: the 85a is just where we learn the source for the nickname קטינא חריך שקי, the short one with burnt legs,

Comment: @Danno That's not just where we see his nickname. That nickname is the end of the story of him testing himself. כל תלתין יומי הוה בדיק נפשיה שגר תנורא סליק ויתיב בגויה ולא הוה שלטא ביה נורא יומא חד יהבו ביה רבנן עינא ואיחרכו שקיה וקרו ליה קטין חריך שקיה

Comment: In the question, 85a is cited as "The short one with singed legs; Bava Metsia 85a". I don't think the question intended to connect any other content with 85a.

Comment: As I mentioned it's not clear who is writing what. At the end of the day my point remains the story of Rabi Zeira and the oven seems to have been confused with the story with Mar Ukva and the oven.

Comment: Am I the only one who sees that this was a great answer?

Comment: @Chaim Apparently. I mean, I thought it was pretty good too:) Thanks for the words of chizuk.